# Tensorflow self-adjoint eigen decomposition not successful, input might not be valid

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to define a custom loss function in Keras with Tensorflow backend which uses only the predicted `y` values, regardless of the true ones. The graph compiles successfully, but at the start of the training it returns an exception: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Self-adjoint eigen decomposition was not successful. The input might not be valid.` I have tried replacing my data with random dummy data, but it produces the same exception.

My full code of the loss definition can be found below. Why is the input to the 
`tf.self_adjoint_eig` not valid?

```
def model_correlation_loss(representation_size, k_singular_values):
    global batch_size

    def keras_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        global batch_size

        regularization_constant_1 = regularization_constant_2 = 1e-4
        epsilon = 1e-12

        o1 = o2 = int(y_pred.shape[1] // 2)

        h_1 = y_pred[:, 0:o1]
        h_2 = y_pred[:, o1:o1+o2]

        h_1 = tf.transpose(h_1)
        h_2 = tf.transpose(h_2)

        m = tf.shape(h_1)[1]

        centered_h_1 = h_1 - tf.cast(tf.divide(1, m),  tf.float32) * tf.matmul(h_1, tf.ones(shape=(m, m)))
        centered_h_2 = h_2 - tf.cast(tf.divide(1, m),  tf.float32) * tf.matmul(h_2, tf.ones(shape=(m, m)))

        sigma_hat_12 = tf.cast(tf.divide(1, m - 1),  tf.float32) * tf.matmul(centered_h_1, tf.transpose(centered_h_2))
        sigma_hat_11 = tf.cast(tf.divide(1, m - 1),  tf.float32) * tf.matmul(centered_h_1, tf.transpose(centered_h_1)) + regularization_constant_1 * tf.eye(num_rows=o1)
        sigma_hat_22 = tf.cast(tf.divide(1, m - 1),  tf.float32) * tf.matmul(centered_h_2, tf.transpose(centered_h_2)) + regularization_constant_2 * tf.eye(num_rows=o2)

        w_1, v_1 = tf.self_adjoint_eig(sigma_hat_11)
        w_2, v_2 = tf.self_adjoint_eig(sigma_hat_22)

        zero = tf.constant(False, dtype=tf.bool)

        idx_pos_entries_1 = tf.where(tf.equal(tf.greater(w_1, epsilon), True))
        idx_pos_entries_1 = tf.reshape(idx_pos_entries_1, [-1, tf.shape(idx_pos_entries_1)[0]])[0]

        w_1 = tf.gather(w_1, idx_pos_entries_1)
        v_1 = tf.gather(v_1, idx_pos_entries_1)

        idx_pos_entries_2 = tf.where(tf.equal(tf.greater(w_2, epsilon), True))
        idx_pos_entries_2 = tf.reshape(idx_pos_entries_2, [-1, tf.shape(idx_pos_entries_2)[0]])[0]
        w_2 = tf.gather(w_2, idx_pos_entries_2)
        v_2 = tf.gather(v_2, idx_pos_entries_2)

        sigma_hat_rootinvert_11 = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(v_1, tf.diag(tf.sqrt(w_1))), tf.transpose(v_1))
        sigma_hat_rootinvert_22 = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(v_2, tf.diag(tf.sqrt(w_2))), tf.transpose(v_2))

        t_matrix = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(sigma_hat_rootinvert_11, sigma_hat_12), sigma_hat_rootinvert_22)

        if k_singular_values == representation_size:    # use all
            correlation = tf.sqrt(tf.trace(tf.matmul(K.transpose(t_matrix), t_matrix)))

        return correlation

    return keras_loss
```

Comment: Did you finally get this to work? I'm having the same issue. Actually, I'm also training a model for doing canonical cross-correlation.

Comment: @mrangry777 Did you get it working then? If so, can you please tell how?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the tf code provided by Wang on his website for computing the loss function:

```
def CCA_loss(H1, H2, N, d1, d2, dim, rcov1, rcov2):
    # Remove mean.
    m1 = tf.reduce_mean(H1, axis=0, keep_dims=True)
    H1 = tf.subtract(H1, m1)

    m2 = tf.reduce_mean(H2, axis=0, keep_dims=True)
    H2 = tf.subtract(H2, m2)

    S11 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(H1), H1) / (N-1) + rcov1 * tf.eye(d1)
    S22 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(H2), H2) / (N-1) + rcov2 * tf.eye(d2)
    S12 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(H1), H2) / (N-1)

    E1, V1 = tf.self_adjoint_eig(S11)
    E2, V2 = tf.self_adjoint_eig(S22)

    # For numerical stability.
    idx1 = tf.where(E1>eps_eig)[:,0]
    E1 = tf.gather(E1, idx1)
    V1 = tf.gather(V1, idx1, axis=1)

    idx2 = tf.where(E2>eps_eig)[:,0]
    E2 = tf.gather(E2, idx2)
    V2 = tf.gather(V2, idx2, axis=1)

    K11 = tf.matmul( tf.matmul(V1, tf.diag(tf.reciprocal(tf.sqrt(E1)))), tf.transpose(V1))
    K22 = tf.matmul( tf.matmul(V2, tf.diag(tf.reciprocal(tf.sqrt(E2)))), tf.transpose(V2))
    T = tf.matmul( tf.matmul(K11, S12), K22)

    # Eigenvalues are sorted in increasing order.
    E2, U = tf.self_adjoint_eig(tf.matmul(T, tf.transpose(T)))

    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.sqrt(E2[-dim:]))
```