# Issue with self_adjoint_eig

Tags: tensorflow

The problem is related to :

[Tensorflow self-adjoint eigen decomposition not successful, input might not be valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108322/tensorflow-self-adjoint-eigen-decomposition-not-successful-input-might-not-be-v)

Is there a workaround to the use of self_adjoint_eig call in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. the problem was with the propagation of NaN from the second loss function that I used for my stacked model.

Comment: Can you explain what caused the NaN's from the second loss function?

Comment: There was a bug in the tensorflow implementation of self_adjoint_eig . I used the numpy implementation with py_func wrapper as a workaround.